# Create a column arch

Tags: architecture, 3dsmax

I would like to create an arch with 2 column but I am a beginner in 3D and i don't know how to make it work. I created the arch model but i am unable to create the column. Can someone tell me how to make it ? or at least point me in a direction? I try to create this 3d model using rhino 5.

The arch looks like in the picture attached : 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The there are two major ways to create a column in the 3d software.
First You may want to check Lathe modifier (as it is called in Autodesk) or under another name in other 3d software. What it is doing generally it wraps the shape that you draw around the axis of choice i.e. XYZ. Thats how you basically achieve a column in a simple way: draw a shape->add lathe (or anther called wrap modifier)->choose an axis.

Second you can box model the column. As it states, you extrude and modify box to achieve the result. Google for box modeling.

Finally, you can mix this techniques. First make an rough column with lathe modifier, second use box modeling technique to modify the object.

Goodluck in your modeling!